# iPhone App Rejected By Apple saying analytics used

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost, nextpeer

One of my iphone app rejected by apple. Here is reason from resolution center.

[image]

> We found that your app uses analytics software to collect and send
>   device data to a third party, which is not in compliance with the iOS
>   Developer Program License Agreement.
>
> 3.3.9 You and Your Applications may not collect user or device data without prior user consent, and then only to provide a service or
>   function that is directly relevant to the use of the Application, or
>   to serve advertising. You may not use analytics software in Your
>   Application to collect and send device data to a third party.
>
> Specifically, your application is transmitting the user's MAC address
>   without their prior consent.  It would be appropriate to either remove
>   this behavior from your application or obtain the user's consent."

Not used any analytics sdk. Only 3rd party sdk used are - Chartboost, Revmob, facebook-ios-sdk, Nextpeer. How can I resolve this problem? how can find which sdk has problem ?

Comment: are you taking user information in your application?

Comment: no, not used from my side..its a iphone game

Comment: Since it says "specifically your application is transmitting the user's MAC address...", I'll guess its the multi-player game platform if it allows you to play without Internet Access / play in AdHoc mode (without using the new API to be available in iOS 7). Since Apple request you to have user's consent, maybe a prompt telling customer some device information is required for the game and ask for a Yes/No answer. Only "Yes" proceed, and see if Apple accepts or not.

Comment: thanks for your reply, let me send this proposed solution in resolution center...lets see what apple reply

Comment: You should just add the UIAltertView and submit a new version.  The resolution center is for when you think Apple misjudged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got reply from apple for same problem. Apple indicated its nextpeer multiplayer sdk issue. User device info is collected in the game. Easy fix is to indicate it in EULA.

See these screenshot.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How are you? This issue most likely wasn't caused by us here at Nextpeer but I will happily look into this for you on our end. If you could please email me (alexander@nextpeer.com) with what SDK version you used during this rejection and your bundle ID, I will check it out for you.

Look forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: one of our team mate already sent message and bundle id to netpeer..they told its not something with nextpeer...let me update all sdk and use UIAltertView as proposed in above comments...lets see what apple do..thanks for the reply.

Comment: finally got reply from apple, its because nextpeer collecting user device info...easy fix is indicate it in EULA.

Answer (score 0):

Nextpeer solved this issue in the 1.5.2 release of the SDK. There is no longer any need to make an addition to the EULA.

How do I know? Because I emailed alexmussafi and asked him :) But he's not found time to update the answer and I wanted to save anyone else the trouble.